# What is the meaning of "values coincides with the convex closure of the eigenvalues"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, vector-fields

In [this](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/77B/jresv77Bn1-2p61_A1b.pdf) paper, it says[image: this].

What is the meaning of the sentence,

"F(M) coincides with the convex closure of the eigenvalues if M is normal."

I understand what is a normal matrix.

But what does it mean to have values which '**coincides** with the **convex closure** of the eigenvalues".

Comment: Kavi has given the definition of *convex closure* below.  In case it's not clear: the phrase “coincides with” is just a fancy way of saying *is equal to* in the quoted sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c_1,c_2,...,c_n$ are the eigen values then the convex closure of eigen values is the set of numbers of the form $\sum a_ic_i$ where $a_i \geq 0$ and $\sum a_i=1$.

Comment: 1) What is the difference between a 'convex closure' and 'closed bounded convex set'?
 2) Is $a_i$ is a vector here? Otherwise, what is the meaning of $\Sigma a_i = 1$?

Comment: @AbhiramVP Here the word closure is not used in the topological sense. It is closure under the operation of forming convex combinations. Sums of the type $\sum a_ic_i$ are called convex combinations of $c_i$'s when $a_i$'s are positive and $\sum a_i=1$.

Comment: However, the convex closure of a finite set is compact in Euclidean spaces.